# Why does this component render twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const AppComponent =()=>{
console.log('rendered');
const parameter = 'apple:two,mango:three'
    .split(',')
    .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      const [key, value] = currentValue.split(':');
      accumulator[key] = value;
    }, {});
return <div/>
}
```

This component renders twice and throws an error. I know that the error is due to their being no return statement in the reduce function. However what I don't understand is why does it render twice?

Further when I remove the `accumulator[key] = value` code it only renders once. As far as I understand, a component can re-render only in four cases

1. change in state
2. change in props
3. forced render
4. parent re-renders.

In my case the **parent doesn't re-render** (I checked it by using a console.log in the parent component) and this component is stateless and no props have been passed to it. Could someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: how can you say it renders twice??

Comment: I have put a console.log("rendered") in the top. It is executed twice. Same for the parent but the console there is not executed twice

Comment: please provide code where AppComponent is called will help to solve it

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
  <AppComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);` Even if we remove the parent component and just try to render this component the behaviour persists.

Comment: i am not facing the same, try to put code on codepane and provide a link here

Comment: I am unable to replicate the behaviour on codepen however I was able to reproduce it in StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-daszph) @JatinParmar

Comment: its because on StackBlits you forgot to clear console on the second run.if you clear the console and refresh the page it only log rendered for first time

Comment: and might be in chrome you set preserve log checked

Comment: pls go to the link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-daszph and try yourself. I haven't preserved the logs. @JatinParmar

Comment: i have checked twice

Comment: comment the error code and then check it

Comment: Did that. Pls go to the mentioned link, comment the accumulator[key] = value; and see for yourself. If you comment it the the component is rendered once. Tried it in my colleague's system too. Further I have also enabled remove logs on reloading in the above link. click the reload button on the small browser like window that you get below the close button in the application (not the browser reload). Further the console is present at the righthand bottom of the page. @JatinParmar

Comment: done there is not error

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your reduce method, you are not returning accumulator..

```
const App=()=> {
  console.log("rendered");
  const parameter = 'apple:two,mango:three'
    .split(',')
    .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      const [key, value] = currentValue.split(':');
      accumulator[key] = value;
      return accumulator; // this line should fix
    }, {});
  return(<div>hello</div>);
}
```

Comment: yeah I get that. My question is  why is that resulting in the component being re-rendered? shouldn't it just throw an error!!

Comment: If you are not getting error then most likely your component is wrapped in Error Boundry, which is causing second re-render. Looks for getDerivedStateFromError or  componentDidCatch in your code base.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-wing-6xh8r. Getting an error but only after second render. Found that the behaviour happens when you try to assign property to an undefined object like in the code given in the link